# Copy file that starts with any number or any letter to a folder

Tags: powershell, wildcard, glob

I need help to construct a code for PowerShell that will copy any file item that starts with any number and also a code for copying files that start with any letter. I currently using something like

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\folder\[a-zA-Z]*.xlxs" -Destination "C:\folder\SUB"
```

Comment: So, you script didn't work? Worked partially?

Answer (score 3):

Simply add `0-9` as another range to the range sub-expression of your wildcard expression:

```
Copy-Item -Path C:\folder\[a-z0-9]*.xlxs C:\folder\SUB
```

Note that I've removed `A-Z`, given that it's unnecessary due to PowerShell's default case-insensitivity.

See [`Get-Help about_Wildcards`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards) and, for a cross-language perspective, the [relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).<sup>Thanks, [TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188846/theincorrigible1).</sup>

Also:

- I'm assuming that by *any number* you mean any *digit*.
- Note that `[a-z]` will only match *ASCII-range* letters, and not accented letters such as `ä`.

Comment: Thanks, @TheIncorrigible1 - I've added your link to the answer, along with a link to PowerShell's own `about_Wildcards` topic.